# How to get a animated pop-up window in MATLAB to display my functions

Tags: linux, fedora, opensuse, matlab

I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask this type of question.  I normally use OpenSUSE x64 systems, but because of issues getting any MATLAB pop-up to work, I switched to Fedora to match exactly what my department had on their computers.

I have installed MATLAB with superuser permissions, and this time, when I run my program, I get a window that pops-up (this didn't happen in OpenSUSE), yet I get no animation in the window.

Since I cannot post the original code, I have borrowed someone's sample code:

```matlab
%// Sample x and y values assumed for demo.
x = 1:1000;
y = x.^2;

%// Plot starts here figure,hold on

%// Set x and y limits of the plot
xlim([min(x(:)) max(x(:))])
ylim([min(y(:)) max(y(:))])

%// Plot point by point
for k = 1:numel(x)
    plot(x(k),y(k),'-') %// Choose your own marker here

    %// MATLAB pauses for 0.001 sec before moving on to execue the next 
    %%// instruction and thus creating animation effect
    pause(0.001);     
end
```

This code runs on the office machine, producing a nice pop-up window with an animated graph.  The window pops up on my machine, but remains grey.  No animation, nor graph shows!  I am running a Fedora 25 x64 system on a Dell Inspiron 13 5368 system.  Any suggestions?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I would try posting this question on http://StackOverflow.com which has a number of different MatLab related tags.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response, I thought I was going to get emails when someone took a look at my question.  @Roflo, thanks for the edit, but I still obtain a grey box.

Comment: I don't have MATLAB, so I can't test it, sorry. But perhaps there's more information you can provide to potential answerers? Maybe a screenshot? Is nothing sent to the console/terminal?

Comment: I think I might have figured out part of the problem.  There seems to be an issue with a .matlab7rc.sh file calling different openGL packages than the ones MATLAB supplies.  My current issue is trying to find how to edit this file.  I can't seem to find it in my system.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have fixed the problem, and it applies to not just animated graphs in MATLAB, but regular ones as well.  For future reference, I will state the problem and the step-by-step solution below:

**Problem**:  MATLAB does not plot or graph in Linux.  Typical error message reads something like:  */usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwosgserver.so':
  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6:
  version 'CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /lib64/libGLU.so.1*

**Solution**:

It appears to be a problem with MATLAB using native openGL packages rather than the ones it installed.  To use them, we edit the file **.matlab7rc.sh**  Now this file is found in the */usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin* folder if you used the default directory to install MATLAB.  Also note that my installed version was *R2016b*, and this will be different from older and newer versions of the program.

Now open a *terminal*, and change your directory to */usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin* (using **cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin**).  Now **.matlab7rc.sh** is a hidden file, denoted by the . preceding the filename.  To check if it is in the folder, type **ls -a** to view hidden files.  Alternatively, one can type **ls -a | less** to interactively scroll through the file contents list.

Once you have determined that the file is there, use the command **sudo kwrite .matlab7rc.sh** to open up the file and edit it.  Note that you need to use *sudo*, or else the file won't save.  Also, I happened to use kwrite, but any editing notepad should be fine.

Once inside the file, un-comment every line that reads:
**LDPATH_PREFIX='$MATLAB/sys/opengl/lib/$ARCH'**

In my case, there were three instances of this line.

Once you have done this, save the file.  If it saved successfully, boot up MATLAB and run your script.  You should get a graph that works!